# Objective-C blocks and variables

Tags: objective-c, variables, objective-c-blocks

I've started using Objective-C blocks today. I wrote the following code:

```
NSArray *array = @[@25, @"abc", @7.2];

void (^print)(NSUInteger index) = ^(NSUInteger index)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", array[index]);
};

for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
    print(n);
```

Which works properly. I needed to change the `array` variable after its declaration, though, so I tried using the following code:

```
NSArray *array;

void (^print)(NSUInteger index) = ^(NSUInteger index)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", array[index]);
};

array = @[@25, @"abc", @7.2];

for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
    print(n);
```

However, that doesn't work. The console just prints `(null)` three times. Why is it that this doesn't work, while it did work with my first piece of code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's because the block captures variables *by value* and *when the block is created* (unless you use `__block`).

What you probably want is:

```
NSArray *array = @[@25, @"abc", @7.2];

void (^print)(NSUInteger index) = ^(NSUInteger index)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", array[index]);
};

for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
    print(n);
```

Example with `__block`:

```
__block NSArray *array;

void (^print)(NSUInteger index) = ^(NSUInteger index)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", array[index]);
};

array = @[@25, @"abc", @7.2];

for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
    print(n);
```

Note that it's a little less efficient to use `__block` if you don't actually need to modify the variable inside the block and have it reflected outside.

Comment: What is the difference while using __block ?

Comment: `__block` tells the compiler to capture the variable by reference, so you can modify it inside the block and have the new value visible outside the block. (I'll add an example with __block.)

Comment: `__block` captures variables by reference.

**Edit:** Beaten on both occasions. :)

Comment: Thanks, using `__block` did it for me. I actually needed to modify my variable inside my block, which works properly now. :)

Comment: i tried with modifying variable inside block with this code, but print three nulls, any idea?     __block NSMutableArray *array;
    
    void (^print)(NSUInteger index) = ^(NSUInteger index)
    {
        [array addObject:@"444"];
        NSLog(@"%@", array[index]);
        
    };
    [array addObject:@"111"];
    [array addObject:@"222"];
    [array addObject:@"333"];

    
    for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++)
        print(n);

Answer (score 3):

The block captures the `array` pointer at creation. You can add `__block` modifier to have the block capture the pointer by reference, but this is usually costly and not recommended. It is better to have the capturing block created after the data is ready to use inside the block.

Comment: interesting did you have an example?