# Saving data from block into an NSMutableDictionary, and blocks in general

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around the best way to use blocks. I am trying to retrieve pedometer data, and the method of accessing the data is a block...

```
[self.pedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate:yesterday
                                        toDate:midnightOfToday
                                   withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *error) {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"Pedometer is NOT available.");
             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"Steps %@", pedometerData.numberOfSteps);
                 yesterdaysNumbersLabel.text = [pedometerData.numberOfSteps stringValue];
                 [pedometerDictionary setValue:[pedometerData.numberOfSteps stringValue] forKey:@"2"];
             }
         });
     }];
```

Using the above code I am able to get the data, log the data, and update the label on the screen, But I can't figure out how to set the data into an array or dictionary so I can do something else with it.

I understand why the arrays and dictionaries are always null... the blocks are running on a different thread and I am accessing them before the blocks have completed.

Can someone help me get through my head how to do something more with the data.

**Update 1:**

Right now I have this in .h

```
@property (strong, atomic) NSMutableDictionary *pedometerDictionary;
```

and I am synthesizing it in .m and I call this...

```
[self getNumbersForYesterday];
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", pedometerDictionary);
```

...which runs the above function and immediately tries to log the result. And like I said, I understand all the reasons it is NOT working. I just need to figure out how to change what i am doing to get it working.

**Update 2:**

This is in .h

```
@property (strong, atomic) NSMutableDictionary *pedometerDictionary;
```

and this is in .m

```
@synthesize pedometerDictionary;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.pedometerDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and I am using it like this.

```
[self getNumbersForYesterday];
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", self.pedometerDictionary);
```

to call this.

```
- (void)getNumbersForYesterday {

    [self.pedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate:yesterday
                                        toDate:midnightOfToday
                                   withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *error) {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             if (error) {
                 NSLog(@"Pedometer is NOT available.");
             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"Steps %@", pedometerData.numberOfSteps);
                 yesterdaysNumbersLabel.text = [pedometerData.numberOfSteps stringValue];
                 [self.pedometerDictionary setValue:[pedometerData.numberOfSteps stringValue] forKey:@"2"];

             }

         });
     }];

}
```

If I just wanted to keep all the work in the block I would be fine. What I have come to understand is that since blocks are asynchronous, I am trying to NSLog my dictionary, and the block isn't finished running yet. So, my dictionary is still NULL.

Comment: Are you looking for [`__block`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12863687/3366929)?

Comment: Don't use `setValue:forKey:` to add an object to a dictionary unless you really have a specific need to use KVC. Use `setObject:forKey:` instead.

Comment: What problem are you really having? Your posted code adds an object to the `pedometerDictionary` dictionary. What's the issue from there?

Comment: The issue is that the dictionary is always NULL, because every way that I try to access it, even just NSLog it, the block hasn't finished when I try to access it. And I can't figure out a way around that.

Comment: you DO allocate pedometerDictionary, right?

Answer (score 1):

Dollars to donuts, your `pedometerDictionary` was never created in the first place (or it was, but the declaration isn't in a useful spot).

I.e. where is your line of code that says `pedometerDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`?   And where is `pedometerDictionary` declared?  How did you try to `NSLog()` values from it?

Also, use `setObject:forKey:`.

---

It is also odd that it is named `pedometerDictionary`.  That is evidence that it is either declared as a global (which it shouldn't be), a local variable of whatever method contains the above code (which won't work), or you are declaring and using an instance variable directly.

Comment: I know this is a whole new tangent, but why bring up `setObject:forKey` and insist on it on an unrelated question. The difference is almost intangible and many would prefer `setValue:forKey:` due to KVO's ability to take a nil value.

Comment: @Conor Why bring it up?  To improve OP's code.  The KVC methods should generally be limited for use against concrete model layer objects.  Dictionary's contract of not taking nil on the setter (and only taking objects) shouldn't be bypassed with KVC just for convenience.  Down that path lies maintenance headaches;   you are far better off with a properly defined model layer.  The worst offense is to mix KVC and non-KVC on the NS* collection classes;  that leads to madness.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating. I shall try to use setObject more often. I've been bitten so many times by setting nil, special when working with JSON data, that I have sworn off setObject.

Comment: And sorry for continuing the tangent, @Conor, but you might also want to check the integrity of your data before passing them on to your model layer. So if you have `null`s from JSAON, catch them and correct them  before you set your data in the model. If `nil` is a valid value for a field, use `[NSNull null]` to store it your collection object.

Comment: @Monolo thank you for the feedback. `setValue:forKey:` lets me use KVO the same way that I would use an optional binding in Swift, to quickly pass JSON values with little if-else clutter code. Although I am of the cult of having a wrist band that says **What would BBum do?** (if humans were compilers he would be `-Wall -Werror`) in this particular case I do not believe it merit the mention of `setObject:` over `setValue:` just for strictness. I wanted to find out if I was overlooking something that @bbum knows that I don't, for those are many things.

Comment: Bbum would write code to validate the structure of the document as @monolo suggested so that I'm not relying on potentially random unexpected values being nil.   Admittedly, more lines of code.  But bbum is in the camp that investing extra lines of code in pedantic error checking up front is preferable to some random subset of customers finding out that an edge server somewhere is barfing up a random unicode character where least expected causing a parse error that leads to an unexpected NULL value from a "null is failure fallback" pattern. I'm old school (emphasis on old) that way. :)

Comment: Bbum is so old school he would use one of those pre compiler directives, a la NSLog, that would wrap the boiler pate code in a single line. I am too young to understand variable argument macros and sadly to old to understand optionals in Swift. @monolo If you ever need to bring Bbum out of the wood work just ask about `retainCount`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is not a block timing issue, your dictionary should never be **nil** at worst it would contain no values.

You need to create your dictionary before using it. The appropriate place would be `init` method for most objects. If you are creating your object in Interface Builder then the method should be `awakeFromNib`.

To do something with the dictionary you can use an NSTimer or call a method from queryPedometerDataFromDate block handler. The use of `@synchronized()` directive is an example of how to keep access to the dictionary from overlapping at the same time in a threaded environment. This is not the case in this particular example as you are dispatching on the main thread and NSTimer also runs on the main thread. But should you go threaded `@synchronized()` would keep you from overlapping access.

```
@interface HelloWorld : NSObject
@property (retain, atomic) NSMutableDictionary *pedometerDictionary;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
@end


@implementation HelloWorld
@synthesize pedometerDictionary, timer;
```

...

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.pedometerDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(doSomethingInterestingWithDictionary:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
    return self;
}
```

or

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.pedometerDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(doSomethingInterestingWithDictionary:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

...

```
- (void)getNumbersForYesterday {
[self.pedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate:yesterday
                                    toDate:midnightOfToday
                               withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *error) {

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Pedometer is NOT available.");
         }
         else {
             NSLog(@"Steps %@", pedometerData.numberOfSteps);
             yesterdaysNumbersLabel.text = [pedometerData.numberOfSteps stringValue];
             @synchronized (self) {
                 [self.pedometerDictionary setValue:[pedometerData.numberOfSteps stringValue] forKey:@"2"];
             }
             [self doSomethingInterestingWithDictionary:nil];
         }
     });
 }];
}


// Will be called when queryPedometerDataFromDate returns and from a timer every 5 seconds.
- (void)doSomethingInterestingWithDictionary:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
    @synchronized (self) {
        NSLog(@"My days dictionary: %@", self.pedometerDictionary);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for adding more info. I think you might still be missing the the `init` call shown above. Also makes sure to always call self. pedometerData to avoid mistakes. As mentioned by bbum don't guess at what code is needed post all of it, and we can help you better.

Comment: Thank you for the extra code. Added `awakeFromNib` as an option instead of init that might be the issue. The code might still have a timing issue as your likely to make it to the NSLog before the dictionary is filled, but it should at least be empty and not nil. In the final version of the code, you would call a method after setting the value that would do something with your dictionary or timer or other interval where you check the previous values.

Comment: " The code might still have a timing issue as your likely to make it to the NSLog before the dictionary is filled [...] In the final version of the code, you would call a method after setting the value that would do something with your dictionary or timer or other interval where you check the previous values " - THIS! This is what I need explained.